# I have 3 fragments in my activity A,B,C

Tags: android-fragments

I have 3 fragments in my activity A,B,C. The flow is A->B,B->C,C->B, A Back pressed app exit,B back pressed app exit. I have an auto logout feature which took fragment C->A but after that when press back button the fragment A moves to C instead of App exit. i have used the below code to go from C->A Fragment. I want when i come from C->A and press back button the application should be exited.

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout_main, ApplicationConstants.loginFragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
//fragmentTransaction.commit();
fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Comment: Just create a stack of fragments and push and pop as you required navigation... for fragments...

Comment: @MPG will you elaborate by giving an example.

Comment: When you display/add a fragment, you have to add into  Stack and when back key pressed pop it from Stack and show/display. but remember one thing do not push duplicate item/fragment